# recording `open` syscalls on mac

Tags: c, bash, macos, system-calls, dtrace

I would like to know what calls are made to `open(2)` in a bash script.

I wrote the following program which intercepts syscalls:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DYLD_INTERPOSE(_replacment,_replacee) \
__attribute__((used)) static struct{ const void* replacment; const void* replacee; } _interpose_##_replacee \
__attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose"))) = { (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacment, (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacee };

static
int
my_open(const char *filename, int oflag, mode_t mode)
{
    printf("$jason$ open: %s\n", filename);
    return open(filename, oflag, mode);
}
DYLD_INTERPOSE(my_open, open)
```

Which I then ran using:

```sh
clang -dynamiclib libfile.c -o libfile.dylib
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=libfile.dylib
touch /tmp/testingtesting
```

It doesn't work.

I tried it with a program that I compiled and it works fine. I tried it with programs compiled by brew and it works fine. I read the source code for [touch.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-321.100.11/touch/touch.c). It calls `open(2)`.

I then disabled SIP and it worked fine. So, I concluded that it was SIP that was causing the problem. I don't want to disable SIP though.

What should I do? I was thinking about just allowing dtrace: `csrutil enable --without dtrace`. Because I think dtrace can track syscalls but I'm not sure if that is a safe option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is called library injection, and Apple works hard to remove this ability from their system.

As a result of their efforts, with SIP enabled, you can do the DYLD_INSERT magic only to the apps that are not hardened (or hardened with several specific exceptions), which I suppose are the apps you built and brew ships.
Apple binaries, one of which is touch, are usually hardened or protected in other ways.

You don't have a big number of options here:

1. Disable SIP and inject what you want
2. Disable SIP partially and you may achieve some goals (dtrace may help)
3. Write a kernel extension doing injection and somehow get the kext signature from the Apple - it could work with SIP enabled.

All these options are for Intel-based macs, for m1 it could be even harder.

Regarding the safety: cut the machine with SIP disabled from the external sources of data (Internet, USB-drives etc), do your research, then enable SIP back and connect mac again to the world.

Answer (score 6):

General library injection has become essentially unsupported on recent versions of macOS.

You can however indeed do this with `dtrace` as you suspect, specifically the `dtruss` script. Unfortunately, the version of this script that ships with macOS is rather stale, so I'd recommend using [my updated version of `dtruss`](https://gitlab.com/pmdj/macos-dtrace-scripts)¹ as this will let you trace all sub-processes, which is pretty essential if you're tracing shell scripts. It also avoids having to run the command you're trying to trace with `sudo`, which might make it behave differently.

This command…

`path/to/dtruss -d -e -f -t open  touch /tmp/testingtesting`

…should work fine with the linked version. Explanation of the command line:

- `-d` and `-e` show call timings. (Optional)
- `-f` enables "follow" mode for also tracing spawned sub-processes - this isn't really interesting for the `touch` command, but you'll probably need it for tracing a bash script.
- `-t open` limits tracing to the `open` syscall. (Leave this off to trace *all* syscalls. Caution: this could produce a LOT of output.)

With the stock version of `dtruss`, you can fall back to:

- `sudo dtruss -d -e -t open  touch /tmp/testingtesting` - but notice that `touch` will be run as the root user in this case, and tracing sub-processes is not supported.
- `sudo dtruss -d -e -t open -n touch`, and then run `touch /tmp/testingtesting` in another terminal. This avoids running `touch` as root, but it will trace **all** processes named `touch`.

The output of the traced syscalls will probably also be less clear when using the original version of `dtruss` as the updated version does a better job of formatting syscall arguments, particularly strings. (For `open()` specifically, [the updated version prints the 'mode' argument for created file permisions as octal](https://gitlab.com/pmdj/macos-dtrace-scripts/-/commit/20f31330bfa62020420d4400c3e8b2b50d455fc4), which is usually what you want.)

And yes, you'll need to disable the dtrace portion of SIP for all features of dtrace to work, and this probably does open a small security risk, but I've not heard of any malware that attempts to exploit this.

**Footnotes:**

¹ I am not trying to self-promote my code. I simply don't know of a better solution - I had a very similar problem to the asker, and the built-in tool was not good enough, so I fixed it.